# asp.net mvc default model binder for model that has inheritance

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, defaultmodelbinder

I have a form that I binding to that has the following structure:

```
public class Status
{
   public List<ABCAttachment> ABCAttachments_Files { get; set; }
}

public class Attachment
{
  public string Id { get; set; }
}

public class ABCAttachment : Attachment
{
   string Name { get; set; }
}
```

My action looks like this:

```
public ActionResult SaveAttachment(Status status)
{
  ....
}
```

The data is coming over in the form

```
ABCAttachments_Files[0].Id="0", ABCAttachments_Files[0].Name="test"
```

When I access status in my SaveAttachments action the Id is there, but the Name is not.  I see it correctly being posted, but why is it not binding properly?

Comment: Are you sure the ID is there? Technically, in your example, it is `default(int)`, and could thus be uninitialized. :)

Comment: @bzlm - sorry I forgot the "" around the 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the `Name` property needs to be public or it won't be bounded to:

```
public class ABCAttachment : Attachment
{
   string Name { get; set; }
}
```

should be

```
public class ABCAttachment : Attachment
{
   public string Name { get; set; }
}
```